# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation jquery.min.js line 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, blobstore

I have written the following code to upload file using blobstore google app engine. I am getting Uncaught TypeError, how to overcome it. Everything works fine but this exception is still there. I tried to add `processData: false` but then the blobstore code receives no upload data from the javascript.

```
$('#insert-sub').click(function (){
    $('#insert-form').validate({
        rules:
        {
            issueName:
            {
                minlength: 2,
                required: true
            },

            issueFilename:
            {
                required: true,
                extension: "pdf",
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form){

            var currentDate = new Date();
            var day = currentDate.getDate();
            var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
            var year = currentDate.getFullYear();

            var issueDate = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;

            $('#issueDate').val(issueDate);

            $('#insertForm').hide();

            filename = $('#issueFile').val();

            var fData = new FormData();

            if(filename.substr(-3) == "pdf")
            {
               $.ajax({
                url: upload_url,
                type: "POST",
                processData: false,
                data: fData,

               });
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Invalid File Extension, upload .pdf")
            }


            }

        });
    });
});`
```

Comment: 1) Note that your `fData` variable holds an empty `FormData` object, you need to use `var fData = new FormData(form);`. 2) What datatype is the response of the AJAX request?

Comment: The response is in json format @RoryMcCrossan